# Using a method in the created Window in QT

Tags: c++, qt

Right now, there is a button for activating the function, like:

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true
    property alias originalImage: originalImage
    title: qsTr("Window1")
    
    Button{
        id: startButton
        x: 50
        y:100
        text: "Open"

        onClicked: {
            VideoStreamer.openVideoCamera()
        }
}
```

But I want to activate this method `just after the window is created`, not with a button click. Like

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true
    property alias originalImage: originalImage
    title: qsTr("Window1")

    VideoStreamer.openVideoCamera()
}
```

But it doesn't work like that. I get `expected token ":"`   error. It expects something like `somecondition:` How am I going to manage this without a button, or without an external user-needed condition like `onclicked:`, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Component.onCompleted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html)** signal to do things right after component is created.

The onCompleted signal handler can be declared on any object. The order of running the handlers is undefined.

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true
    property alias originalImage: originalImage
    title: qsTr("Window1")
    
    Component.onCompleted: 
    {
        VideoStreamer.openVideoCamera()
    }
}
```

P.S.: if your VideoStreamer is an QML object maybe it is a better to use this signal directly there.